# Find the first occurrence of a string in m:m relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL where tables `a` and `b` are m:m relationship — how can I find all occurrences of strings that:

- occur in both `a.string` and `b.string` columns
- AND occurs in `b.string` before it occurs in `a.string` based on order of `ab.id`

E.g., `"hello"` occurs in both columns `a.string` and `b.string` AND appears first in `b.string` according to order by `ab.id`, so `"hello"` would be returned as a result.

Something like:

```
select *
from table ab
left join table a on (a.id = ab.a_id)
left join table b on (b.id = ab.b_id)
-- pseudo: 
  -- where b.string "hello" occurs first
  -- and a.string "hello" also exists
order by ab.id


ab.id | ab.a_id | ab.b_id | a.string | b.string 
-----------------------------------------------------
  1      63        59       'good bye'   > 'hello' -- appears first here
  2      75        67       > 'hello'    'sounds good'
  3      77        78       'have fun'   'awesome'
```

---

**EDIT:**

Basically, the idea is that the user should always first see a string in the form of column a.string, then b.string. If b.string instance ever appears first, we should return this.

Two situations I need to account for where the condition above **IS NOT** satisfied.

**1)** `b.string` meets the condition of appearing before `a.string`, but it's not the first instance of `a.string`'s "hello" - i.e., in row 1 `a.string` and `b.string` are "hello", but then row 2 satisfied the condition of `b.string`'s "hello" appearing before `a.string`:

```
ab.id | ab.a_id | ab.b_id | a.string | b.string 
-----------------------------------------------------
  1      63        59       'hello'      > 'hello' -- meets condition
  2      75        67       > 'hello'    'sounds good'
  3      77        78       'have fun'   'awesome'
```

**2)** `a.string` appearing at some other point when `b.string` was NULL, then any other following row condition of `b.string` appearing before `a.string` should be FALSE

```
ab.id | ab.a_id | ab.b_id | a.string | b.string 
-----------------------------------------------------
  1      63        59       'hello'      NULL
  2      75        67       'good bye'   'hello'
  3      77        78       'hello'      'awesome'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two conditions.  Exists and not exists come to mind:

```
select ab.*
from ab
where not exists (select 1
                  from ab ab2
                  where ab2.astring = ab.bstring and
                        ab2.id < ab.id
                 ) and  -- no earlier "a"s
      exists (select 1
              from ab ab2
              where ab2.astring = ab.bstring 
             )          -- another "a"
```

Comment: This is a bit confusing to me— table `ab` is just a `m:m` table of `a` and `b`, therefore `ab.string` wouldn't exist. Also, are you simply omitting the joins for sake of brevity?